# How to check whether the value of an attribute is not null or if the length of characters in the value of an attribute is greater than 0

Tags: xslt

`s0SelectedSite` is an attribute of a class or a column of a table.

```
<xsl:if test="string-length(@s0SelectedSite) &gt; '0'">
<tr>
  <td width="50%" bgcolor="#C0C0C0"><font size="2"><b>Selected Site:</b></font></td>
  <td><font size="2">&#160;<xsl:apply-templates select="DBE:Attribute   [@name='s0SelectedSite']"/></font></td>
</tr> 
</xsl:if>
```

In the above, the value of `s0SelectedSite` exists but still the lines are not getting printed.

For eg. It should display the following:-

```
Selected Site:             Singapore
```

Please let me know if something is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I find this generally works for checking to see if a tag is populated

```
<xsl:if test="@s0SelectedSite !=''">
```

Could you provide a sample of the xml, as I use this all the time and am wondering if the xpath is the issue.

Comment: Hello Rob, welcome. Start the line with 4 spaces for code formatting, or select the code and click the code button (101010)

Comment: I tried this but it did not work.
I got the below error in tomcat
ERROR:  'null'
FATAL ERROR:  'Could not compile stylesheet'

Answer (score 1):

1. Try `<xsl:if test="string-length(@s0SelectedSite) &gt; 0">` (and not `'0'`).
2. Try `<xsl:if test="@s0SelectedSite">` , see if it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way now --> It worked for me :

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="string-length(DBE:Attribute[@name='s0SelectedSite']/node()) &gt; 0"> 
    <table>
...
    </table>
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <table>
...
    </table>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: <xsl:when test="string-length(DBE:Attribute[@name='s0SelectedSite']/node()) &gt; 0"> ..........worked

Comment: Hello Prashant Rao, welcome. Start the line with 4 spaces for code formatting, or select the code and click the code button (101010). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to all for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i use it in a template.
It matches every @dateEnd that's not empty.

```
<xsl:template match="@dateEnd[. != '']">
   ...
</xsl:template>
```